# I'm trying to make the Fibonacci sequence but each digit is a specific coloured square, how do I do it?

Tags: python, colors, fibonacci

I am trying to make a piece of code in python that generates the Fibonacci sequence and then colour code each digit.

So far I have:

```
import time

a = 1
b = 1
while True:
  al = str(list(str(a)))
  bl = str(list(str(b)))
  print(al)
  time.sleep(0.25)
  print(bl)
  time.sleep(0.25)
  a = a+b
  b = a+b
```

but I don't know how to colour code the digits, let alone how to render any shapes.

edit: sorry for the confusion, I meant for each digit to have a different colour as in 0 being red up to 9 being green (or other colours)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print colored text to the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-do-i-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to print colored output is to use the colorama module.  you can find the documentation here https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style 
print(Fore.RED + 'text in red color')
print(Back.GREEN + 'text with green background')
print(Style.RESET_ALL) #to reset whenever needed
```

for example, this will print each character in alternate color

```
import time
import colorama

def print_list_in_color(al):
    count = 0
    for i in al:
        count +=1
        if count%2 == 0 :
            print (colorama.Fore.RED + i,end='')
        else :
            print (colorama.Fore.GREEN + i,end='')
        print (colorama.Style.RESET_ALL,end='')
    print()

a = 1
b = 1
while True:
  al = str(list(str(a)))
  bl = str(list(str(b)))
  print_list_in_color(al)
  time.sleep(0.25)
  print_list_in_color(bl)
  time.sleep(0.25)
  a = a+b
  b = a+b
```

and simply this will print each list in alternate color

```
import time
import colorama

a = 1
b = 1
while True:
  al = str(list(str(a)))
  bl = str(list(str(b)))
  print(colorama.Fore.RED+al)
  time.sleep(0.25)
  print(colorama.Fore.GREEN+bl)
  time.sleep(0.25)
  a = a+b
  b = a+b
```

for each digit to have a different color, you can modify the function in the following way. I have just added the mapping for 0,1 and 9 as an example and everything else defaults to YELLOW, you can add the mapping for the rest of the digits in the same dictionary

```
colormap = {'0':Fore.RED,'1':Fore.GREEN,'9':Fore.BLUE}

def print_list_in_color(al):
    count = 0
    for i in al:
        count +=1
        if i in colormap :
            print (colormap[i] + i,end='')
        else :
            print (colorama.Fore.YELLOW + i,end='')
        print (colorama.Style.RESET_ALL,end='')
    print()
```

also if u simply use

```
  al = str(a)
  bl = str(b)
```

instead of

```
  al = str(list(str(a)))
  bl = str(list(str(b)))
```

the output would seem prettier

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I meant for each digit to have a different colour as in 0 being red up to 9 being green (or other colours)

Comment: If you couldn't tell, I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: hey, that is absolutely fine. I have edited the answer accordingly. I have added it for 0,1,9 as example, you can add the mapping for the rest of the digits in the same dictionary

Comment: as in 
```
import time
import colorama

a = 1
b = 1
while True:
  al = str(a)
  bl = str(b)
  time.sleep(0.25)
  print(al)
  time.sleep(0.25)
  print(bl)
  a = a+b
  b = a+b
  colormap = {'0':Fore.RED,'1':Fore.GREEN,'9':Fore.BLUE}
  def print_list_in_color(al):
    count = 0
    for i in al:
        count +=1
        if i in colormap :
            print (colormap[i] + i,end='')
        else :
            print (colorama.Fore.YELLOW + i,end='')
        print (colorama.Style.RESET_ALL,end='')
    print()
```
?

Comment: yeah, just add the digits in the dictionary, like {'0':Fore.RED, '1':Fore.GREEN,'2':Fore.BLUE, '3':Fore.PINK,'4':Fore.ORANGE, ...... and so on till .. '9': Fore.BROWN}

Comment: yh I thought so but it wasnt working. I figured out the problem, though so I got it working. thanks

Comment: is there any way to do something like this but to replace parts of a string with other things in a dictionary? something like replacemap = {'hello': 'goodbye'} would mean that in the string any 'hello's would be replaced with 'goodbye's. I'm making these to try out making a module but I also want to get better at python in general since I'm not very good at it.

Comment: nvm, I made something that works.